# jQuery: load method - reload a specific part of a page without url?

Tags: jquery, load

i wondered if it's possible to just reload a specific div of a page without passing a url?

```
    $('a.reload').live('click', function(e) {
        $sv.load(" #inside")
    });
```

if I click the reload-link i want just to reload the div with the ID inside on the current page. Is there a trick on how to do so with jquery?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible, but luckily you can pass the URL for the page with `window.location.href` and then filter out everything but the thing you want:

```
$('#inside').load(window.location.href + ' #inside');
```