# How to refresh a div

Tags: jquery, html, refresh

I have the DIV below :

`<div id=conteudo></div>`

```
var div= document.getElementById("conteudo");
div.setAttribute("height","55");
```

I want to refresh the div, is there a way to do that with jquery?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261308/jquery-load-method-reload-a-specific-part-of-a-page-without-url

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="conteudo"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#conteudo').css("height", "55px");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to refresh the content in the div that is coming from the server? If so, you can use $.load from jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

more specifically under the "Loading Page Fragments" section...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Jquery and This worked for me.( to reload a Table)

```
$('table#table_id').load(window.location.href + ' table#table_id');
```